# Proving Big-Omega

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have a tutorial sheet that asks:

Prove that $n^2 - 3$ is $\Omega(n^2)$

I understand that:

$$f(n) ≥ c g(n) $$

And that to $c > 0$ & $n > n_{0}$

The problem is that what ever $C$ value I use I keep ending up where the $n^2$ value shall fall into the negative domain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. For all $n\geq 2,$ $$\frac{n^{2}-3}{n^{2}}\geq \frac{1}{4},$$ right?

Comment: @RideTheWavelet we have to use the definition, f(n)  ≥ c g(n) to prove that n² - 3 is Ω(n²), so I need to find either a trivial case of C or use some other form of proof. Does that help clarify?

Comment: Doesn't what I've written do exactly that?

Comment: @RideTheWavelet how did you know what c value to pick?

Comment: Well for this example, I saw that when $n=1,$ I got $-2$ as the value, but once I picked $n=2,$ I got something positive. Since the left hand side is increasing in $n,$ $1/4$ works. We could just as well have chosen $n_{0}=3$ and $c=2/3.$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the help and explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{n^2}2$ remains below $n^2-3$ as of $n=3$. Then you have it.